# Possible to hide TCP ip for clients?

Tags: networking, tcp

this is my first post so...

I'm quite new to networking, I just started transferring data over TCP and everything is working fine. I am hosting a small chat server (Made in Autoit v3) on my own network, but what bothers me is that all the clients could simply track the ip on which the server is hosted...

As I don't want to be 'hacked' I would like to know if there is a way to hide the ip on which the server is hosted. Maybe routing it through another network if that is possible.. As I said I have pretty much 0 experience with networking, I can port forward and setup a simple server but that is pretty much it :)

Thanks everyone!

Comment: The IP address is how other connect to your server. Unless others know your IP address, they cannot connect to your server. TCP addresses (ports) are at a different network stack layer. You cannot connect to a server only by knowing the TCP address. For example, HTTP (web) servers all use TCP port 80 by default. You must know the IP address in order to connect to a particular web server using TCP port 80.

Answer (score 0):

When you are opening up any service to the world, you should secure via IPsec or TLS/SSL like services, further more you should open only those ports on the IP which is required by that service.

example: a.b.c.d:8080 for HTTP so instead have it on HTTPS(port 443) that means a.b.c.d:443. HTTPS requires TLS/SSL certificate and you can get them from [here](https://letsencrypt.org/).

For your service TLS/SSL should suffice the needs because it works over transport layer.